# Selecting Option Based on Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically select an option, based on a passed variable, that matches only the value of that option.

[JS Fiddle Link Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fvw6Lqc6/)

```
<label>
    <span>Font Type</span>
    <select id="options>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two" selected>Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
</label>

function loadSelect(userFont){
    $('#options').find('option[value='+userFont+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}

loadSelect(three);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the value on the `<select>` tag:

```
$('#options').val(userFont);
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#options").val("three");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think it's time for coffee and some sleep after not realizing how easy it was :D Thanks.